# Не запускается Firefox

Tags: linux, ubuntu, elementary-os

Всем привет.

ОС — *Elementary OS Freya, 3.16.0-34-generic*.

Ранее устанавливал скачанный с сайта Firefox в домашнюю директорию в `opt/firefox/firefox`. После благополучно все удалил, почистил там где есть упоминания о нём и установил его `apt-get`-ом, всё легло как надо:

- /usr/bin/firefox
- /etc/firefox
- /usr/lib/firefox
- /usr/bin/X11/firefox
- /usr/share/man/man1/firefox.1.gz

Прописал в `.bashrc`:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/firefox
export PATH
```

При запуске firefox в консоли получаю:

> ```
> devup@devup-Aspire-E3-112:~$ firefox 
>
> [1] 3822
>
> bash: opt/firefox/firefox: No such file or directory
>
> [1]+  Exit 127                opt/firefox/firefox
> ```

При запуске по полному пути (`/usr/bin/firefox`) firefox стартует.

Подскажите, почему?

Comment: `PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/firefox export PATH` - `/usr/bin/firefox` - это не каталог, его не нужно добавлять в список PATH. Более того, там `/usr/bin` скорее всего и так есть.
Скорее всего Вы везде пути поудаляли, а переменные среды "не прогрузили". можно через `source .bashrc`, но лучше просто перезайдите в сессию (или ещё лучше - ребутните машину).

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо.Путь действительно был прописан, я невнимательно посмотрел, .bashrc тоже зря правил.

Подскажите, о каких путях, который я поудалял, идет речь? где?
После установки firefox я перезагружал машину.

Comment: KoVadim, вероятно, имел в виду каталог `opt/firefox` (или `opt/firefox/firefox`)

Comment: у меня есть смутное подозрение, что где то есть симлинк с firefox на opt/firefox.  Я бы посмотрел в вывод `whereis firefox`

Comment: @KoVadim, я его(whereis firefox) собственно и привел в начале темы:/usr/bin/firefox
/etc/firefox
/usr/lib/firefox
/usr/bin/X11/firefox
/usr/share/man/man1/firefox.1.gz

Comment: тогда есть ещё вариант, что кто то прописал firefox в alias (посмотреть на `alias firefox`)

Comment: @KoVadim, слушайте, да! Кроме меня никто не мог, видимо забыл, спасибо.